Resized images with .NET vs PDFs
First, just to say, I know there are a ton of questions and answers here about image resizing in .NET, and believe me I have spent hours looking into this. I find it intriguing, and still feel I must be missing something, that somehow a simple PDF file can display an image at any size it wants and retain a far higher image quality than can be obtained using .NET.
I have an PNG image at 1000x1000px. It has some embedded text.
Using the iTextSharp PDF libray, I save it in a PDF file at 300x300:
.ScaleAbsolute(300, 300)

The result is very good - a nice high quality image, showing clear text.
Then, to try and reduce the file size, I use .NET to first reduce the image size - pretty standard .NET stuff - using a graphics object g:
  g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
  g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality
  g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality
  g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality

Save this, and again create my PDF.
The resulting image, viewed in the PDF or even directly in an image viewer, is of a far lower quality, particularly noticeable around the text.
My question is: if a PDF can resize an image on the fly and retain its high quality, why can't .NET create one to begin with? Or can it? Is there some method other than the standard .NET code that can achieve this?
After some Googling, I did try an alternative method, using a helper function
   Friend Function GetEncoderInfo(ByVal mimeType As String) As ImageCodecInfo
      Dim j As Integer
      Dim encoders As ImageCodecInfo()
      encoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
      For j = 0 To encoders.Length
         If encoders(j).MimeType = mimeType Then
            'adp.WriteLog("", "got it " & mimeType, True)
            Return encoders(j)
        End If
      Next j
      Return Nothing
   End Function

and then in the main routine:
Dim compression As Long = 255 ' lower value is poor quality, high is better.
Dim myImageCodecInfo As ImageCodecInfo
Dim myEncoder As Encoder
Dim myEncoderParameter As EncoderParameter
Dim myEncoderParameters As EncoderParameters
myImageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/png")
myEncoder = Encoder.Quality
myEncoderParameters = New EncoderParameters(1)
myEncoderParameter = New EncoderParameter(myEncoder, compression)
myEncoderParameters.Param(0) = myEncoderParameter

then the standard graphics code, and then saving it with
Save([path], myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters)

but tbh I couldn't see any difference in the resulting image to the original straightforward method. (I'm not really sure it's nothing more than a fancy way of simply asking for it be saved in PNG Format anyway, but IDK.)
I have different InterpolationMode settings.
Anyway, back to my question: is there a better way of saving a resized image in HQ? PDF's manage it easily enough, so can't .NET? What's a PDF doing that .NET isn't? In theory, I'd get a better result from taking a screenshot of the original image resized in the PDF!

A PDF will typically store high-resolution images (excepting someone printing from Word...); the ScaleAbsolute() call in your iText code (probably) does not resample the image, it just sets the physical (i.e. paper) dimensions of the image on-page (inches, mm, points, etc). That's probably why it looks so crisp/high-quality to you: because as you zoom-in in Acrobat you're still looking at the high-res original.

I get that, but it doesn't alter the fact that even before zooming in the PDF displays it better. In effect, why can't .NET create an image that looks just like what the PDF displays  before zooming in. If I look at my PDF with a zoom level that displays the image at 300x300 on my screen, it looks much better than a 300x300 image created by .NET.  There must / ought to be a way round this.

Please take a screenshot (that shows both your image and the PDF's image, side-by-side) and add it to your post so we can (literally) see what you're talking about.

Thanks Dai - I've answered my own question, below.

Hmm.. ok, I may have to concede defeat on this. Dai (commenting above) is right, in that I wasn't really taking into account how small 300x300 is and wasn't viewing the PDFs at 100% but a higher zoom.
It seems that with a standard A4 size PDF setting, the max resolution is about 560px wide, and with the layout I need this doesn't leave room for a larger image display size than 300x300, but when viewing you really have to zoom the whole thing in. Hence the loss of quality.
Prob nothing can be done other than go for the larger file size.

"Resolution" is perhaps the wrong word but when using the iTextSharp library after setting the PageSize to A4,, if I set the image size to anything large than about 560 (allowing a margin setting of 10) then it won't fit.
